# How do I create settings only used by my theme?

Tags: options, variables

I have a theme that when installed will check to see if the necessary pages are there and if not they will be created (this is for a website not a blog). I'm trying to create settings that will be updated from false to true once each page has been created so that functions.php isn't continuously checking the page's existence.

I've looked into global variables (which is advised against) and register_setting which requires a form. I don't want settings that are visible or can be modified manually but only by the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to register_settigs, you can just add the options straight to the database with [`add_option()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option).

You could have like a dummy option "all_pages_created" and if that's set then don't check for the individual pages.

```
if (get_option('all_pages_created') !== false) {
// it's set, do nothing }
else { // check for your pages and update individual_pages_option with update_option()
       // and when all pages are created add_option('all_pages_created', 'true', '', 'yes' )
}
```

Or something like that. It shouldn't be too hard...